# How to handle 'done' button on an Android keyboard app with AngularJS/Ionic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm creating an hybrid mobile app using AngularJS, Cordova, and Ionic framework.

Here is an Android 5.0 keyboard. Take a look at the blue button in the bottom-right corner.

[image]

I'd like to do 2 things:

1. Control which "type" of button displays (sometimes it's a "next" button, a "done" button, or a "search" button. The icon changes.)
2. Control the behaviour of this button. For example, I'm signin up and typing my name in a first fied. In my case, the default behaviour of the keyboard button is to submit the form instead of going to the next field. I'd like to control this button to go to the next field.

All topics I found talked about native Android app with Java code.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
//add this event

(keyup.enter)="addInput()"
```

Answer (score 0):

Good question. But definetly it has answer at this [resource](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/getting-the-keyboard-go-button-to-act-like-the-app-submit-was-clicked/5305/3)

one of many ways to do is by controlling keycodes. For enter keycode is 13:

```
$scope.keyPressed = function(keyEvent, formModel) {
    if (keyEvent.keyCode == 13) {
        $scope.formSubmit(formModel);
    }
};
```

another possible way is:

> you can use either `ng-click` or `ng-submit` button.  WARN: Do not use
>   both.

```
 <form ng-submit="submitLogin()">
  <input id="entry1" ng-model="id_entry"  type="text" >

  <button type="submit" class="button" ng-click="idSubmit()">
  Login</button>
</form>
```

This is a summary from the link shared. Works well for me. Hope this helps.